# Seeking open source solution to access rasters in File Geodatabase?

Tags: gdal, file-geodatabase, c++, file-geodatabase-api

I'm looking for a way to access raster layers in an Esri File-GeoDatabase without using `ArcObjects` or `ArcPy`, specifically I would like to access the raster layers with `GDAL`. I understand that the `GDAL` `FileGDB` and `OpenFileGDB` give access to vector datasets within File-GeoDatabases, and that ESRI's own `FileGDB` C++ API does not support raster access.

Is anyone out there aware of any open source solutions?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821571/working-with-rasters-in-file-geodatabase-gdb-with-gdal

Comment: Reverse-engineering rasters isn't likely to be simple.  There's a reason it's still a "ToDo" in OpenFGDB.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've just released a prototype program [Arc Raster Rescue](https://github.com/r-barnes/ArcRasterRescue) which extracts raster data from the ArcGIS File Geodatabase format.